# installing SQLite3 gem on remote FreeBSD server using RVM - root permissions needed?

Tags: freebsd, rvm, gem

I am trying to install ruby SQLite3 gem, on a remote freebsd server. I'm using RVM which in theory does not need 'root permission' to compile gems but I get a root error, here:

> [user ~]$ gem install sqlite3 --
>   --with-sqlite3-dir=/home/www/atma/opt/ [...]
>
> make install /usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel -m 0755
>   sqlite3_native.so /home/www/atma/.gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3
>   install:
>   /home/www/atma/.gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so:
>   chown/chgrp: Operation not permitted make: ***
>   [/home/www/atma/.gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so]
>   Error 71
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/www/atma/.gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection. Results logged
>   to /home/www/atma/.gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

Any ideas how to approach this? Maybe re-installing RVM?

best regards,
PA

Comment: What are the permissions in the target folders? Can't you modify them accordingly?

Comment: define "accordingly"...

Answer (score 0):

try installing the `ruby` version:

```
gem install sqlite3 --platform ruby
```

I'm not sure if you need to add path for sqlite3 dir but this should not require `.so` files - and most likely would skip the part of installing them.

Comment: Solved it, was a lame RVM error..